# Does aspnet_regsql do anything more than create the tables necessary for Membership?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

If I've already run the `aspnet_regsql.exe` tool on a database that will be used with ASP.NET Membership, can I dump that database on a remote server without the server needing to run the tool again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `aspnet_regsql.exe` tool creates the necessary schema on your database, there is no other magic performed on the machine.

Everything should work fine after moving your database to another server, you will not have to re-run this tool.